# error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::python::detail::reference_existing_object_requires_a_pointer_or_reference_return_type<R>'

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr, boost-python

I get the error reference_existing_object_requires_a_pointer_or_reference_return_type.

Here's the code.

```
boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic> GetCdbWrapper(boost::shared_ptr<A> cmd)
    {
        return cmd->Cdb();
    }
}

virtual boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic> Cdb() { 
    boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic> CdbObj;
    return CdbObj;
}
boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic> GetCdb() { 
    return this->Cdb(); 
}


class_<A, bases<Core::CommandBase>, boost::shared_ptr<A>, boost::noncopyable, >("A",
    ":description:\n",
    boost::python::no_init
)

.def("Cdb", &A::GetCdb,
    ":description:\n",
    return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()
);
```

May I know what's wrong in above code. I get the compilation error as below.

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::python::detail::reference_existing_object_requires_a_pointer_or_reference_return_type<R>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            R=result_t
1>        ]
1>        c:\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost\python\detail\caller.hpp(200) : while compiling class template member function 'PyObject *boost::python::detail::caller_arity<1>::impl<F,Policies,Sig>::operator ()(PyObject *,PyObject *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            F=boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic> (__thiscall A::* )(void),
1>            Policies=boost::python::return_value_policy<boost::python::reference_existing_object>,
1>            Sig=boost::mpl::vector2<boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic>, A &>
1>        ]
```

Comment: From what I can see (without further knowledge of the boost implementation) the `reference_existing_object` policy requires the object returned to be of pointer or reference type. `shared_ptr` is neither pointer nor reference but a class type and it is returned by value in your code. Although, `shared_ptr` is a resource-managing pointer wrapping class, it is not a pointer itself. I don't think `reference_existing_object` is required when using smart pointers.

Comment: Thank you. removing  return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>() resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [`return_internal_reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_internal_reference.html) documentation, the object returned references an existing internal object via either a pointer or reference:

> `return_internal_reference` [...] allow pointers and references to objects held internally [...] to be returned safely without making a copy of the referent.

Boost.Python provides some concept checks, and often the type accentuates the failed concept.  In this particular case, the compiler error has:

```
reference_existing_object_requires_a_pointer_or_reference_return_type
```

This is because the `GetCdb()` function returns a `boost::shared_ptr<CDB::Basic>` by value, failing to meet the requirements for the `return_internal_reference` call policy.  To resolve this, use the default call policy of returning a copy by value.  This requires that the `CDB::Basic` be exposed through Boost.Python as being held by a `boost::shared_ptr`.  Overall, this behavior is not too different than what is often used with a `shared_ptr`, where one creates copies of the `shared_ptr` to maintain shared ownership.

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0066c074aa7ea36) this behavior:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// Mocks...
class spam {};

boost::shared_ptr<spam> get_spam()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<spam> spam_ptr(new spam());
  return spam_ptr;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<spam, boost::shared_ptr<spam>, boost::noncopyable>(
      "Spam", python::no_init);
  python::def("get_spam", &get_spam);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.get_spam()
>>> assert(type(spam) is example.Spam)
```

Comment: I was able to bypass the compilation error by keeping below code.                    class_<A, boost::shared_ptr<A>, boost::noncopyable, >("A",
    ":description:\n",
    boost::python::no_init
)

.def("Cdb", &A::GetCdb,
    ":description:\n"
); But while building and installing the project, I get "Assertion Failed C:\Python27\python.exe File: libs\python\src\converter\registry.cpp. Line 212 Expression: slot->m_to_python==0 error. could this assertion error be a result of above code?

Comment: @user3665224 I believe that assertion indicates a type is trying to be registered multiple times.  For instance, if you have multiple `class_<A, ...>` calls.  If you build a release version of the Boost.Python library, a warning message will print out type information as to which class is being registered multiple times.

Comment: Perfect. That helped.!